# jQuery.load and form elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

Is jQuery's .load() supposed to be able to load <form> elements?  Because it seems to be stripping them out.  So I have some code like:

```
$('<div></div>').load($link.attr('href') + ' #divDlgContent', function(){ ... });
```

and when the $dialogcontents loads, I return some content with a <form> inside the DIV with the id 'divDlgContent'.  Although the rest of the HTML inside the DIV is loaded, the <form> tags are stripped out.  Is this by design, and is there a way I can load <form> elements this way?

Comment: Can you show the html contents of #divDlgContent?
jQuery only removes `<script>...</script>` tags when using load() so I guess something is wrong with your HTML.

Comment: Did you close the <form> tags correctly on the HTML you want to load? Do divDlgContent elements exist in the HTML you want to load?

Comment: I think it's OK... here's the output that the .load() is receiving:
http://pastebin.com/6Umghr3j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guy in this thread seems to have had a similar problem:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-jquery-stripping-form-tags

It's such a long time ago I was dealing with this problem that I can't remember what my fix was.  I think I either had 2 `<form>` tags in the document and `.load()` didn't like that, or it was a problem at a browser level, not a jQuery level, because `.innerHTML` didn't like `<form>` tags.